# KeyListener is lagging

Tags: java, multithreading, keylistener

I am not sure why my key listener is not working. Basically I have a key that prints a map on the screen for a robot navigating a 2d maze. When the robot is manual (it listens to key commands), my keylistener works. When the robot is automatic, the keylistener only fires after the robot stops moving or when it finds an exit. Since the program runs the robot when it is automatic, is there any chance the key listener not being able to fire instantly have to do with threads? I am really confused. 
Here is the code, sorry if it looks ugly or confusing, I've commented the relevant parts.

```
private void start() {
    if (selectedMaze != 0) {
        maze.method = selectedMaze;
    }
    if (robot instanceof BasicRobot && driver instanceof ManualDriver) { //If Robot is Manual
        kd = new ManualDriverKeyListener(this, maze, (ManualDriver) driver);
        addKeyListener(kd);
    } else { //If Robot is not manual, thus automatic
        km = new MinimalKeyListener(this, maze);
        addKeyListener(km);
    }
    if (!(robot instanceof BasicRobot) && !(driver instanceof ManualDriver)) {
        try {
            driver.drive2Exit(); //This operates the Automatic Robot
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I know `MinimalKeyListener` works since I've put a System.out.print statement in there. However, the Keylistener only prints when the Automatic Robot stops moving. Is this a problem with threads?

Comment: I don't think that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to understand your problem enough to answer it. Hopefully I'm wrong, but if not, and f you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like 'drive2Exit' is running in the main thread, preventing the keylistener events from working. Maybe run it in a different thread?

Comment: @sje397 How do you know what `drive2Exit` actually does?

Comment: @sje397 Thanks, that is what I was thinking.

Comment: @MadProgrammer complete guesswork :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer drive2Exit tells the robot what to do based on a maze algorithm. It is running on the main thread and it is pretty intensive in resources, so maybe that is preventing keylistener from firing instantly.

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and remember, Swing is not thread safe ;)

Comment: @Renren29 I have no doubt you're on the right track, but have no context to go by ;)